# Automount LVM logical volume with a udev rule and udisks2

Tags: lvm, udev, automounting, external-hdd, udisks

I want to automatically mount an LVM logical volume on an external drive as soon as it is connected to the computer.

The solution I choose here is to use `udev` to detect plug in events and `udisks2` to mount the partition. For other alternatives see [a more generic approach of logical volume auto-mounting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127511/automatically-mount-a-logical-volume-on-an-external-disk-drive-lvm-partitioned)

I am asking for knowing if my approach of `udev` and `udisks2` is doomed or if it is my achievement that failed. The following is a brief sum-up of all my attempt.

## The simplest udev rule that does not work

To my mind `udev` rules seems to be appropriate to assert drive presence and set `UDISKS_AUTO` for the given partition so `udisks2` can automount the partition. Therefore I created the following rule in its own file `/etc/udev/rules.d/61-lvm-automount-lv.rules`

```bsh
SUBSYSTEM=="block"\
, ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="<UUID of my LV>"\
, ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}="1"
```

Then I reload the rules `sudo udevadm control --reload` (or even better restart my computer), check that the rule is read and UDISKS_AUTO is set to one for the given partition `sudo udevadm test /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-1` and confirm that in the end of the output I can see `UDISKS_AUTO=1`

However, when I unlplug/plug the external disk the partition is not mounted automatically.

I tried to find the maximum of information about what's going wrong thanks to `journactl`, `udisksctl monitor` but the only useful messages was from `udevadm monitor --environment --udev` showing that:

```
UDEV  [3897.839040] change   /devices/virtual/block/dm-1 (block)
.ID_FS_TYPE_NEW=ext4
ACTION=change
DEVLINKS=/dev/mapper/wdhdd0-wd0 /dev/disk/by-uuid/b32cefaa-041e-4ef7-8c82-fe53739aefff /dev/disk/by-label/wd /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-wdhdd0-wd0 /dev/wdhdd0/wd0 /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-hwQrCjWSOCCGpJqcdPv3NHaP3OOK6kFQj2Y6j3X51A69FEYNQeHtt8wVnVnlb93N
DEVNAME=/dev/dm-1
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/dm-1
DEVTYPE=disk
DM_ACTIVATION=1
DM_COOKIE=6324838
DM_LV_LAYER=
DM_LV_NAME=wd0
DM_NAME=wdhdd0-wd0
DM_SUSPENDED=0
DM_UDEV_DISABLE_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_FLAG=1
DM_UDEV_PRIMARY_SOURCE_FLAG=1
DM_UDEV_RULES=1
DM_UDEV_RULES_VSN=2
DM_UUID=LVM-hwQrCjWSOCCGpJqcdPv3NHaP3OOK6kFQj2Y6j3X51A69FEYNQeHtt8wVnVnlb93N
DM_VG_NAME=wdhdd0
ID_FS_LABEL=wd
ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=wd
ID_FS_TYPE=ext4
ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
ID_FS_UUID=b32cefaa-041e-4ef7-8c82-fe53739aefff
ID_FS_UUID_ENC=b32cefaa-041e-4ef7-8c82-fe53739aefff
ID_FS_VERSION=1.0
MAJOR=253
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=6641
SUBSYSTEM=block
TAGS=:systemd:
UDISKS_AUTO=1
USEC_INITIALIZED=5756122
```

So it seems that udisks2 should automatically mount this partition thanks to `UDISKS_AUTO=1` but no. However, I can still execute `udisksctl mount -b /dev/wdhdd0/wd0` and now the partition is mounted manually.

## Other rules that does not work

Changing the value of `UDISKS_SYSTEM` since logical volume might be interpret as system volume hence has to be hidden by default

```bsh
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="b32cefaa-041e-4ef7-8c82-fe53739aefff", ENV{UDISKS_SYSTEM}="0", ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}="1"
```

Add a rule to unignore the physical volume containing the logical volume with `ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="0"`. I understand perfectly why physical volume has to be hidden and not mounted in the filesystem but I though that maybe the logical volume inherit some properties.

Change the order in which rules are loaded, it requires to change the number `61` in the beginning of the name of the file `61-lvm-automount-lv.rules`. To set my simple rule earlier in the order of the udev files to be loaded first it requires adding `IMPORT{builtin}="blkid"` in the beginning of the rule for those who wants to try. Conversely, I tried to put the simple rule in the end.

However these attempts leads to no improvements whatsoever

### My last insight about udev

My last idea was to make `udev` start the shell command I use to mount the LV manually `/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/wdhdd0/wd0` at the right time that is after the PV has been successfully mounted. So I naively tried the following rule with name `991-mountthatstupidcomputer.rules` to be evaluated last:

```bsh
ACTION=="add"\
, SUBSYSTEM=="block"\
, ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="<UUID of my PV>"\
, RUN{program}+="/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/wdhdd0/wd0"
```

According to the man page of udev about `RUN`

> add a program to the list of programs to be executed after processing all the rules for a specific event

So it should have been done ! But no once again automount failed and I could see why in the log. In fact the script is executed right after udev has considered the event add on the given PV has been finished. However, that was without counting on the nasty `dmsetup` thing I did not know about. It seems that all the LVM setup is delayed so when udev execute my script the PV is not yet mounted. In Ubuntu, I could find the usage of dmsetup in the rules:

- 55-dm.rules:52
- 95-dm-notify.rules:12

That the point where I am stuck right now. There might be a solution based on this DM_COOKIE that dm_setup seems to use but I gave up while I was looking at the dm_setup manual. It definitely seems to me that I have dug to deep here for a problem as simple as mounting a partition. I might have missed something simpler somewhere. Also, I would like to stick with standard tools and not too much scripting all over my system that will broke sooner or latter.

## Goal

Ultimately, I would like that a given logical volume could be automatically mounted by my system exactly as standard (non-lvm) partitions are usually mounted. I am open to any suggestion on the best way to do that. I oriented this question with udev and udisks2 because it seems to do a perfect job for standard partition under Ubuntu, so I would like to achieve the same thing for LVM.

## Edit

My `/var/log/syslog` right after plugging in the disk with the simplest rule in the beginning:

```
[12766.403419] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[12766.553014] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1003
[12766.553020] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[12766.553024] usb 1-1: Product: External HDD    
[12766.553029] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital 
[12766.553032] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 57442D574D41565531333130343938
[12766.553817] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[12766.554314] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
upowerd[2160]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
upowerd[2160]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1
kernel: [12767.564246] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access  WD 15EARS External  1.75 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
kernel: [12767.565075] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
kernel: [12767.565196] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] 2930277168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.50 TB/1.36 TiB)
kernel: [12767.565482] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
kernel: [12767.565487] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
kernel: [12767.565740] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
kernel: [12767.565749] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
kernel: [12767.620230]  sdc: sdc1
kernel: [12767.621669] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
systemd[1]: Starting LVM2 PV scan on device 8:33...
lvm[31988]:   1 logical volume(s) in volume group "wdhdd0" now active
systemd[1]: Started LVM2 PV scan on device 8:33.
```

Comment: This should work automatically. As far as I know, there is nothing special about LVs in this context - they are just another block device. But the place to look for problems/error messages are the system logs in `/var/log`, specifically `message` and `syslog`. What do those say?

Comment: I'd also recommend checking out [udiskie](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie). That's what I use. It's packaged for Debian, and thus for Ubuntu. And it sounds like you are using Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes thanks for your advice I'll edit the main post with the content of syslog right after the disk is plugged in. Also I have seen udiskie while I was browsing the documentation and all the help I could find about udisks and udev, but I hav not tried udiskie yet so I'll try that latter and report my experience.

Comment: However I have no /var/log/messages or anything similar maybe it has been removed from Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Yes I have already posted the content of '/var/log/syslog' messages at the bottom of my main post however I cannot see anything wrong in it

Comment: Ok. Those logs show no mounting happening. Do any of the lines refer to a mount? And have you tried using `udiskie`? First step is to get `udiskie` to do a manual mount. Once you can do a manual mount, hopefully you can configure it to happen automatically.

Comment: I'm on my way to install and use udiskie however manual mount is not a problem. I always succeed to mount my partition thanks to `udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/wdhdd0-wd0` or classic `mount` or in GUI via nautilus

Comment: Just to be clear, can you manually mount the LV in question?

Comment: Yes I can manually mount the LV partition

Comment: I tried udiskie but it does not work neither to automount nor to mount manually. I have tried with udiskie as a daemon, udiskie-mount, and with the .config/udiskie/config.yml

Comment: What errors do you get? "Does not work" isn't useful information. You do need to give ukdiskie extra permissions via policykit. Without that it won't work. See `/usr/share/doc/udiskie/README.Debian`. I wrote that, actually.

Comment: Yes sorry for the short answer but I though debugging udiskie was out of the scope of this question. So the detailed error after a udiskie-mount is : `udiskie.mount: not mounting /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d5: unhandled device` also in the debug right before I see this `IgnoreDevice(match={'is_external': False}, ignore=True) used for /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d5` which seems weird because the device is my external drive but maybe intended for LV since only the PV is seen as external usb drive.

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems udiskie doesn't support LVM as I was going through the code of udiskie I did not find anything related to LVM and it seems to be confirmed by another project I am intersted in [helm-linux-disks](https://github.com/akirak/helm-linux-disks) which assert that udiskie is great indeed except that it does not support LVM

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing special about LVM. It's just a block device like any other block device. So it does not require any special code. Please provide a link where it says that `udiskie` does not support LVM. It's also possible to check with the `udiskie` maintainer - he does respond to queries/bug reports etc.

Comment: Never mind, I see it does say that in the https://github.com/akirak/helm-linux-disks page. And there is a reference in one of the `udiskie` issues to adding support for LVM. I'll ask the `udiskie` maintainer. You could ask him too.